# Command to check if can access to Websocket address & port

Tags: websocket, socket.io, ws

I'm looking for a command like:

```
ping google.com
```

But I also want to use the port, like `google.com:8080`

I want to know if a client can connect to my servers socket listener at a certain port.

My core problem is, 100% of users are able to connect to my websocket port at 8080, but only single digit x% are able to connect to websocket port at 2053. This is independent of device. After research I've found out that some ISPs might be blocking this port.